# Change the default background that fades from

Tags: boot, desktop-background

Whenever I start Ubuntu there is always the default purple background that then fades to my custom desktop background. How do I remove/change it?

Comment: has to do with the login screen background. You can change that if you want. I have written a script specifically bfor that, let me know if you want link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your login greeter wallpaper to match your user wallpaper:

1. Copy your desired wallpaper into `/usr/share/backgrounds` (make sure it's readable by "other")
2. Open dconf-editor and go to `com > canonical > desktop > unity-greeter`
3. Change the `background` entry to the path of your desired wallpaper: `/usr/share/backgrounds/[your desired wallpaper]`

Next time you logout and log back in, you should see your desired wallpaper on the login screen.